# JavaScript localStorage of image src doesn't work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage, gsap

I have 2 array of path items:

```
var images = [
    imgPath + 'earth-png/a1.png',
    imgPath + 'earth-png/a2.png',
    ...
var images2 = [
    imgPath + 'eye-lens/01.png',
    imgPath + 'eye-lens/02.png',
    imgPath + 'eye-lens/03.png',
    ...
```

Then in order to make an animation with multiple images, I try to load it first :

```
this.loadImages = function() {

    if (typeof(Storage) == "undefined" ) {
        console.log("Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.");
        return false;
    } 
    else {
        console.log("Both localStorage and sessionStorage support is there.");
    }

    var totalImg = images.length + images2.length
        i = 0,
        j = 0
        var myImages1 = [];
        var myImages2 = [];

    function loadImgs() {
        if (i < totalImg && (myImages1Storage.length > 0 && myImages2Storage.length > 0)) {
            if (i < 20) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: images[i],
                    crossDomain: true,
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: false
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        myImages1.push(images[i]);
                        i++;
                        loadImgs();                     
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: images2[j],
                    crossDomain: true,
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: false
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        myImages2.push(images2[j]);
                        j++;
                        i++;
                        loadImgs();                     
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            try {
              localStorage.setItem("images1", JSON.stringify(myImages1));
              localStorage.setItem("images2", JSON.stringify(myImages2));
            }
            catch (e) {
                if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
                    console.log("Error: Local Storage limit exceeds.");
                } else {
                    console.log("Error: Saving to local storage.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    loadImgs();
};
```

And then, to the TimelineMax:

```
eyeLensAnimation
    .to(obj, 0.5, {
        curImg: images2.length,
        roundProps: "curImg",
        immediateRender: true,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        onUpdate: function() {
            //next image on update
            eyePng.src = images2[obj.curImg];
        }
    });
```

Well, here comes my question.

As you can see, I store the data in a localStorage. It seems to be successful when I go through the array load with a:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("images1"));
```

Nevertheless, it seems to work only with Chrome.
With Firefox, it continues to request a get when it's time to trigger the animation (on scroll with scrollmagic).

So, is there something I do wrong?

Should I load first the array stored and use the array loaded as path for my animation or does it not occur if - at least - the path asked is already stored in cache?

Comment: `myImages1Storage` and `myImages2Storage` . where did you initialize these both variables ?

Comment: Yeah sry, it is in the general object, just under the array 'images' / 'images2'.
Not in a function.

Comment: you better provide  a fiddle or you full js